# tailwindcss row-span-full doesn't working

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to render a category list use dl list.
dl is grid container which has 7 columns and dt if one of the 7 which occupies all of grid container rows.
I dont's set the rows number, because it decided by the column nums.But `row-span-full` didn't work.
If I set a static row number for dl, there may be many white space when the grid container's really rows number is less than what I set.

I use React + tailwindcss.

```js
Object.keys(data).map((category, idx) => (
  <dl key={category} className="grid grid-cols-[140px_repeat(6,_1fr)] p-4 gap-y-2">
    <dt className="row-span-full">{category}</dt>
    {data[category].map((item, i) => (
      <dd className="text-sm" key={i}>
        {item.name}
      </dd>
    ))}
  </dl>
));
```

I expect dt occupies all rows of grid container even if I don't set the row number.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic set the row nums.

```js
{
  Object.keys(data).map((category, idx) => (
    <dl
      key={category}
      style={{ "--rows": `repeat(${Math.round(data[category].length / 6)}, 1fr)` }}
      className="grid grid-cols-[140px_repeat(6,_1fr)] grid-rows-[--rows] p-4 gap-y-2"
    >
      <dt className="row-span-full">{category}</dt>
      {data[category].map((item, i) => (
        <dd className="text-sm" key={i}>
          {item.name}
        </dd>
      ))}
    </dl>
  ));
}
```